# Return a list to Many2One field

Tags: python, odoo-11, odoo-12

I have a   class Branch, class BranchLine, class Product, and class ReqTrans, the idea is to make a transfer request of products from one branch to another, what i want to do is when a user selects a certain branch, the available products should only be visible the classes are as follows

```
class CustomBranch(models.Model): 
    _name = 'custom.branch' 
    _description = 'Branch Record' 
    _rec_name = 'branch_name' 

    branch_name = fields.Char(string="Branch Name", required=False, ) 
    branch_line = fields.One2many('custom.branch.line', 'branch_id', string='Branch Lines', )

class CustomBranchLine(models.Model): 
    _name = 'custom.branch.line' 
    _description = 'Branch Line Record' 

    branch_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string='Branch') 
    product_id = fields.Many2one('custom.product', string='Product') 
    qty = fields.Integer(string="QTY", required=False, )

class CustomTransRequest(models.Model): 
    _name = 'custom.trans.request' 
    _description = 'Transfer Request' 

branch_from_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string="From") 
branch_to_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string="To") 
product_ids = fields.Many2many('custom.product', string="Line") 

@api.onchange('branch_from_id') 
def onchange_branch_from(self): 
        for rec in self: 
            selected_lines = rec.env['custom.branch.line'].search([('branch_id', '=', rec.branch_from_id.id)]) 
            products = [] 
            for line in selected_lines: 
                 products.append([line.product_id.product_name, line.id]) 
        return products
```

How do i return products to products_ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@api.onchange('branch_from_id') 
def onchange_branch_from(self):
   for rec in self: 
      selected_products = rec.env['custom.branch.line'].search([('branch_id', '=', rec.branch_from_id.id)]).mapped('product_id')
      self.product_ids = [(6, 0, selected_products.ids)]
```

Try this

Comment: Thank you so much it did work and retrieved the wanted products, 
but what are the 6 and 0 for? what do they mean
also the desired products got populated as if the user have selected them already in the many2one field, is there i way to display them like a combobox?

Comment: Details about 6,0 fileds
http://www.odooninja.com/update-many2many-field/

Comment: You can use domain then it will show the suggestions of those products not added them in list.

Comment: I tried the below code

`@api.onchange('branch_from_id')
    def onchange_branch_from(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.branch_from_id:
                return {'domain': {'product_ids': [('branch_id', '=', rec.branch_from_id.id)]}}`

but i got this error

 _raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field 'branch_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('branch_id', '=', 3) on custom_product (ctx: )>"_